# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I'm receiving the following JSON from the server:

[image]

And then I'm trying to map it using $.map in the AJAX call's `success`, as follows:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: urlGetStaticData,
        success: function (data) {
            self.AvailableTags(data[0].Value);
            self.MeasurementUnits($.map(data[1].Value, function (item) { return ko.mapping.fromJS(item) }));
```

and the last line throws the following exception:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string

when it tries to map the property with the `Symbol` name.

From what I've read, javascript has recently (or atleast had planned to) added a "new Symbol primitive type". Could this issue be related? What workaround is there? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MikeC I think the real question here is, how is a Symbol instance involved here in the first place? It can't come from a `JSON.parse()` result.

Comment: If `data` is deserialized JSON, it won't have any `Symbol`-named properties or `Symbol` values, so I can't see how you could be running into this. Can you create an [MCVE](/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem here is that KO is trying to use a function called `Symbol` (because KO observables are functions) because one of the properties in your data is called `Symbol`. But on an ES2015 engine, there will be a global `Symbol` function as part of the JavaScript environment. So KO calls that function instead, gets a `Symbol` back instead of what it's expecting, and then (apparently) does some operation that attempts to coerce that value to a string. Which fails. (I'm not sure *why* it ends up calling the global `Symbol` rather than something shadowing it, but KO uses some fairly complex dynamic code and `with` statements, so...)

This would be a bug in the KO mapper brought on by recent JavaScript language changes. As a short-term fix, rename the property before mapping it.

Comment: @MikeC: Big time. :-)