# node error when inspecting objects created in C++

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon

I have a (large) piece of code that is in C++ as an add-on for nodejs. Part of the code makes nodejs to throw internally an exception when I try to inspect the object that exports the module.

```
TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string
    at Object.objectToString (internal/util.js:84:36)
    at isError (internal/util.js:80:18)
    at formatValue (util.js:408:9)
    at formatProperty (util.js:781:15)
    at util.js:641:12
    at Array.map (native)
    at formatObject (util.js:640:15)
    at formatValue (util.js:579:16)
    at formatProperty (util.js:781:15)
    at util.js:641:12
```

I was investigating a bit and I found that the Named Properties (or Interceptors) I have makes this happen. If I comment out the set to the export object of this Properties, the object shows in node with all the functions and variables I expose from C++.

To create and set the Named Properties I use a macro I create for it, but basically does this:

```
Local<ObjectTemplate> someFuncVar = Nan::New<ObjectTemplate>();
Nan::SetNamedPropertyHandler(someFuncVar, someFunc);
Nan::Set(target, Nan::New("someFunc").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::NewInstance(someFuncVar).ToLocalChecked());
```

The getter function returns numbers for some certain inputs, otherwise return undefined. An example of that:

```
NAN_PROPERTY_GETTER(DecWriteStatus) {
    Nan::Utf8String propertyName(property);
    std::string PropertyName(*propertyName);

    if(PropertyName == "CONTINUE") info.GetReturnValue().Set(0);
    else if(PropertyName == "ABORT") info.GetReturnValue().Set(1);
    else info.GetReturnValue().SetUndefined();
}
```

My question is if it is possible to fix "this problem" and avoid the exception thrown when inspecting the object with the Named Properties.

I use node 6.3.1, and Nan 2.4.0. *Seems that problem on Linux, with everything the same, works. Maybe this only happens on OS X.*

To test this strange behavior, you can download [my project](https://github.com/melchor629/node-flac-bindings), build it (you will need libFLAC installed somewhere) and try to execute in node this lines:

```
 > const f = require('bindings')('flac-bindings');
 > f
```

If it shows the object with the `f.load()` function, call it with the full path to the flac library and will show the error too.

Comment: Do you have a complete, minimal, and reproducible example posted somewhere?

Comment: Minimal no, but my project at all yes, https://github.com/melchor629/node-flac-bindings. In src/decoder.cpp, src/encoder.cpp and src/format.cpp are the files where Named Properties are used.

Comment: Perhaps, there is problem with `Symbol` method of C++-object - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34996890/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-convert-a-symbol-value-to-a-string

Comment: I don't use `Symbol` in any part of the C++ code and I don't export anything named `Symbol`. I read this question before posting that, and I think cannot be this.

Comment: FWIW your repo code works for me on Linux with node v6.3.1.

Comment: Wow, maybe it only happens in OS X (I'm using it). Or my local build has been corrupted in some strange way (because I cleaned the binaries a few times).